# Point coordinates after deformation?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, three.js, coordinates

I have a chart like this:

[image: Before]

Point O is in a rectangle and dependent to rectangle edges.

After I drag point B (corner), the rectangle is deformed like this:

[image: After]

How I can calculate the coordinates of point O after deformation?

I work in JavaScript, so if You could, I would like an algorithm. Thanks for all and sorry for english bads!

Comment: Is point O's relation to the edges 'dynamic' or 'static', meaning will the x offset from B always be 13 or will it change if x changes?

Comment: O is relation to the edges dynamic

Comment: Ok, could you provide a snippet that you are using to draw the charts?

Comment: I am using Graph: http://www.padowan.dk/download/

Comment: Ok, but you're wanting to do this in JS? I'm confused...

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using the WebGL with three.js for the JS. I just need calculation, the script i will write on own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, get the relative positions of your point in the rectangle:

posXRel = (O.x - A.x) / (B.x - A.x);

posYRel = (O.y - A.y) / (B.y - A.y);

Find the position of those relative coordinates on the lines of your quad A’B’C’D’

*In A’B’:* 
posAB.x = A’.x + posXRel * (B’.x - A’.x); 
posAB.y = A’.y + posXRel * (B’.y - A’.y);

*In B’C’:* 
posBC.x = B’.x + posYRel * (C’.x - B’.x); 
posBC.y = B’.y + posYRel * (C’.y - B’.y);

*In C’D’:*
posCD.x = C’.x + posXRel * (D’.x - C’.x);
posCD.y = C’.y + posXRel * (D’.y - C’.y);

*In D’A:*
posDA.x = D’.x + posYRel * (A’.x - D’.x);
posDA.y = D’.y + posYRel * (A’.y - D’.y);

Now we want to get the intersection between the line which go from posAB to posCD and the line which go from posBC to posDA:

To do that we need to set the equation:
Y = aX + b for those two lines and get a and b.

*For the line which go from posAB to posCD:*

a1 = (posAB.y - posCD.y) / (posAB.x - posCD.x);

b1 = posAB.y - a1 * posAB.x;

*For the line which go from posBC to posDA:*

a2 = (posBC.y - posDA.y) / (posBC.x - posDA.x);

b2 = posBC.y - a2 * posBC.x;

Finally we are looking for the solution of the equation:

a1 * O’.x + b1 = a2 * O’.x + b2;

So your new coordinates should be:

**O’.x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
O’.y = a1 * O’.x + b1;**

Can you tell me if it works?

Comment: Yes it's works. Thanks, but I now done writing algorithm for http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dyer/cs534/slides/13-morphing.pdf

Comment: Well, take a look at that: https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/cinder-warping-block-released

Answer (score 0):

I think to recalculate new position of O, you need to do:

1. Before you move point B, calculate what part of each side O takes. i.e.

   oPositionX = O.x/(B.x-A.x);
   oPositionY = O.y/(B.y-C.y);
2. When you moved B you can restore new position of O as:

   O.x =  oPositionX*(B.x-A.x) + A.x;
   O.y =  oPositionY*(B.y-C.y) + C.y;

Not sure about algorithm but i think main concept should be like that.

Comment: After calculation, point O I get out of rectangle bound. So I think that these formules i incorrect